# Measuring the bias of a machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, training-data

How can we measure the bias of a machine learning model? Can we determine it by just calculating its performance estimates difference on the train data and test data?  For example, if a model SVM predicts on train data is 0.53 and then on test data it is 0.60; can we say that the bias is just 7 points?

I have read an article which mentioned that "The bias of a model validation technique is often measured in terms of the difference between a performance estimate that is derived from a model validation technique and the model performance on unseen data." 
[Diagram about this here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHpHR.png)

Thanks

Comment: The bias should be the difference between the unavoidable bias (the best possible predictor with that data) and your train accuracy. E.g., to predict if someone is sick, the best predictor should be a team of specialized doctors, and their accurracy is not 100%, but let's say 95%. Let's say your model acc is 80%, now you avoidable bias is 15% (95% - 80%).

Comment: Also, I think this is not the right place to ask that question. You should ask here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: @alan.elkin, thanks. let me ask there.. But when you say " accuracy is 95%", do you mean accuracy with train data and then 80% accuracy is accuracy with test data? train data - test data = 15% ?

Comment: No, test data is more related to the `variance` and should not be involved in the bias error. I highly recommend you watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZf3oo0fuh0) for clarification. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @alan.elkin, thanks for your information.

Comment: @alan.elkin, I have added a diagram in original post.. What does the author mean by unseen data here? test data or validation data? In the paper, the authors just talked about the train/test data and not the validation data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the last question in the comments, I think you are referring to other usages of bias and variance.

In the field of statistics, the [bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) is referred to an offset (systematic error) in the prediction or an estimator.

In the field of neural networks, bias error is referred to the difference of your `train error` againt the best possible `error`.

When training a neural network, you show the model several examples to learn from (train set) and examples not to learn from, but to measure performance (validation set or also named dev set). The difference between `train error` and `validation/dev error` is called `variance` and gives you a notion of how well your model is generalizing to unseen data.

As you will probably train several models until you are happy with the results, you will select the best one based on its `validation/dev error`. This may involve some kind of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) to the hyperparameters as you only kept the models with best performance in the `validation/dev error`.

To be sure you are not doing so (overfitting hyperparameters), you can use a third set called test set of unseen examples and not to learn from. If the `validation/dev error` is very similar to the `test error`, then (generally) you can conclude that your model has no overfitting on the hyperparameters and should perform as good as in your dev set.

Again, I highly recommend you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZf3oo0fuh0) for more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AsadAli Does this answer your question?

Comment: I am going to accept your answer. Thanks and sorry for late response.